# (React Native) UseEffect Return is executed after navigating to another page is complete

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, navigation

This code is an example of the problem I'm facing.

```
import {useEffect} from 'react';
import {Pressable, Text} from 'react-native';

function page1() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(1); 1️⃣  

    return () => {
      console.log(2); 2️⃣
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <Pressable onPress={() => navigation.navigate('page1')}>
      <Text>BUTTON</Text>
    </Pressable>
  );
}

function page2() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(3); 3️⃣   

    return () => {
      console.log(4); 4️⃣
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <Pressable onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
      <Text>BUTTON</Text>
    </Pressable>
  );
}
```

When the screen is moved from **page1** to **page2**, I expected it to run in the following order

```
1️⃣ console.log(1); // when on page1
2️⃣ console.log(2); // When leaving page1
3️⃣ console.log(3); // when on page2
4️⃣ console.log(4); // when leaving page2
```

However, the actual results were as follows

```
1️⃣ console.log(1); // when on page1
❓ Nothing happens // When leaving page1
3️⃣ console.log(3); // when on page2 ❓
2️⃣ console.log(2); // When on page2 ❓
4️⃣ console.log(4); // when exiting page2
```

Steps 2 and 3 is being reversed.
The useEffet return logic on page1 is running on page2 and affecting it.

Is there a good way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This is what actually happens:

**1, 3, 4**

- `setup` function (1) is called when `page1` is added
- **Navigate to page2**
- `setup` function (3) is called when `page2` is added
- **Go back**
- `cleanup` function (4) is called when `page2` is removed

`page1` is never removed so `cleanup` function (2) is not called

See details for [useEffect](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect).

---

Use [useFocusEffect](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/) to detect when a page comes into and goes out of focus.

**1, 3, 2, 4, 1**

- `setup` function (1) is called when `page1` comes into focus
- **Navigate to page2**
- `setup` function (3) is called when `page2` comes into focus
- `cleanup` function (2) is called when `page1` goes out of focus
- **Go back**
- `cleanup` function (4) is called when `page2` goes out of focus
- `setup` function (1) is called when `page1` comes into focus

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. However, I tried replacing useEffet with useFocusEffect on page1, but it's still the same: 1, 3, 2, 4. (You wrote it that way!!)

I want it to run in the order 1, 2, 3, 4 in the page1 -> page2 process. Is there a good way to do this?